# swift 3 How to add UITextView programmatically then remove it when click the button?

Tags: dynamic, swift3, uitextview

I am newbie on swift 3. I have this situation: I need to create textview dynamically also the remove button below it...so there is button to add field (textview) dynamically then there's button below it to remove it..and I put those on view.. Let say "placeholderCD"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1d8ck.png)

But the problem is..how or what action i need to put when the remove button click? because we can not assigned the id of dynamically button right? so my code like below :

```
func AddCommentItem(sender:UIButton){
    /** CREATE TEXT VIEW **/
    let textView: UITextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: (newX + 20), width: 311.00, height: 50.00));
    textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.justified
    //textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    let borderColor = UIColor.lightGray
    textView.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
    textView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    textView.tag = tagname
    /** CREATE TEXT VIEW **/

    /** CREATE REMOVE TEXT VIEW **/
    let btnRemove: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 240, y: (newX + 52), width: 100, height: 50))
    //btnRemove.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    btnRemove.setTitle("Remove", for: .normal)
    btnRemove.titleLabel?.font = btnRemove.titleLabel?.font.withSize(10)
    btnRemove.tag = tagname

    btnRemove.setTitleColor(UIColor.gray, for: .normal)
    btnRemove.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnRemoveComment), for: .touchUpInside)
    //btnRemove.tag = 1

    /** CREATE REMOVE TEXT VIEW **/

    cell.placeholderCD.addSubview(textView)
    cell.placeholderCD.addSubview(btnRemove)
}

func btnRemoveComment(Sender:UIButton) {
   /** HOW I REMOVE THE Related text view object with this action **/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove the textview by tag

```
cell.placeholderCD.viewWithTag(yourTag)?.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: oh cool..let me try in minutes...by the way tag just can be fill with Integer right? can i add like string to make unique? sorry i am new..thank you!

Comment: no tag is only int , you can assign your IndexPath.row for each textField to make them unique

Comment: the reason i ask that because i need to remove some elements not just textview on that placeholder

Comment: you can assign same tag to all elements

Comment: thank you for your help @Jaydeep Vyas it work but just one element remove which is correct the textview..but i have another element like label and remove button it self...by the way..how you usually name it on tag so to be unique? i know indexpath.row will be show the row but if many elements? any idea? thank you so much before!

Comment: one more suggestion  for you just add all element in single view which you want to remove and then assign tag to it. it will be easy to maintain

Comment: oh thank you! but if i put same tag on all elements i think just first element assigned to be remove..so i think each element should be have unique?

Comment: no you have to write , `cell.placeholderCD.viewWithTag(yourTag)?.removeFromSuperview()` this line multiple times (as per number of element you remove like 3)

Comment: awesome awesome! i am very appreciate it..it worked!! thank you you are very smart!